# Как в слайдере выводить события календаря?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, карусель, calendar

Есть сайт на wordpress c установленными плагинами календаря [The Events Calendar](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/) и адаптивного слайдера [LayerSlider](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246)
Хочу выводить в слайдере ближайшие мероприятия, которые создаются через testimonials - как это можно сделать или посоветуйте другой слайдер, который точно умеет это делать.

Answer (score 2):

Советую вам слайдер [OwlCarousel2-Thimbs](https://github.com/gijsroge/OwlCarousel2-Thumbs). Ему без разницы, какой контент выводить. Я использую это плагин для вывода изображений из мета-поля, вам же ничто не мешает получить массив записей и вывести их с помощью `foreach()`. Надеюсь, это вам поможет.

Comment: спасибо, буду стараться воспользоваться им - о результатах отпишусь